# Disaster Recovery Solution for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, disaster-recovery

How i find solution disaster recovery solution for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) in case i use on-premise is DR site for AKS? who you recommend possible solution? or use case scenario.

BR Thanakrit

Comment: Kindly refer- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1529780/disaster-recovery-solution-for-azure-kubernetes-se and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ha-dr-overview

Answer (score 0):

**AKS doesn't have a built-in, one-click disaster recovery solution** that can be enabled from the Azure portal UI. Disaster recovery in AKS typically involves a combination of best practices and strategies that you must configure manually.

These can include multi-region deployment, data replication, backup and restore strategies, and more. Microsoft recommends running multiple AKS clusters in alternative regions, configuring active-active, active-standby, or [active-passive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/active-passive-solution) solutions for your AKS clusters, and utilizing disaster recovery features for your database tier, such as geo-redundant backups and deploying read replicas in a different region.
[image: For High availability]

[image]

> Deploy additional AKS clusters in different Azure regions using the
> Azure portal. Ensure that these clusters have similar configurations
> to your primary cluster.

***why?***

When you create an application in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and choose an Azure region during resource creation, it's a single-region app. When the region becomes unavailable during a disaster, your application also becomes unavailable. If you create an identical deployment in a secondary Azure region, your application becomes less susceptible to a single-region disaster, which guarantees business continuity, and any data replication across the regions lets you recover your last application state.

For *ACR geo-replication*, navigate to your Azure Container Registry in the Azure portal, go to "Setting-> Networks->Geo replication" and add the regions where you want to replicate your images.
[image]

For *Azure Traffic Manager*, create a new Traffic Manager profile in the Azure portal, and configure endpoint monitoring and routing methods that suit your disaster recovery strategy.
[image]

all the above mentioned points ensures a complete disaster recovery plan.

As for using on-premises as a DR site for AKS, Microsoft recommends extending your deployment to an alternative region instead. You can select an alternative region based on your consideration for available services, capacity, geographical proximity, and data sovereignty. Please review the Azure regions decision guide for more information.

References:

- [High availability and disaster recovery overview for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ha-dr-overview#high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-overview-for-azure-kubernetes-service-aks)
- [Migrate Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and MySQL Flexible Server workloads to availability zone support - Disaster recovery considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/migrate-workload-aks-mysql#disaster-recovery-considerations)
- [Active-passive disaster recovery solution overview for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/active-passive-solution#active-passive-disaster-recovery-solution-overview-for-azure-kubernetes-service-aks)
- [Backup and recovery for AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/operator-guides/aks/aks-backup-and-recovery#backup-and-recovery-for-aks)